# Selecting Launch Image for Portrait Retina will de-select the image selected for Portrait non-Retina

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am using the latest xCode 5 and I am trying to set Launch Images for my universal app. When I selected Launch images for iPhone, everything went fine. But now, when I am trying to select Launch images for iPad, there seems to be some bug in xCode, or main be I am doing something wrong.

-> I select an Image for iPad - Portrait Non-Retina (everything OK)

-> Now I select an Image for iPad - Portrait Retina (the image selected in above step will be de-selected automatically)

[image]

In the above image, an image was selected for the highlighted Portrait Non-Retina before I selected an image for Portrait Retina.
And this makes it impossible to select images for the last four items in the list shown in the image.

Comment: Are you using files with the same name, or does your retina image have the @2x suffix?

Comment: @GuyKogus the naming is like: `splash_ipadretina_portrait.png` and `splash_ipad_portrait.png`

Comment: Renaming with @2x worked. I was expecting xCode will do the renaming thing itself if it's really needed. Just like it does with the iPhone Launch images.

Comment: @GuyKogus Can you please post your suggestion as an answer? I'll select it as accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use the @2x suffix convention for Xcode to recognise the retina image.

Comment: It's strange that xCode renames the Launch Images for iPhone as needed. But when you upload Launch Images for iPad, it leaves the renaming on you :-)

Comment: I added my launch images directly into the Images.xcassets folder in Xcode, which doesn't rename them, which was actually frustrating because I thought that it would.

Answer (score 1):

use your images with format: imageName@2x.png The compiler will automatic set images for retina screen